# Scaffolding existing database to my application I get this error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting

Tags: sql-server, server, blazor, scaffolding

I am trying to do an scaffold from my existing database to my application.

I am using Blazor Server 6.0
My database is hosted in Azure
The string connection that I am using on my application I got it from Azure
The My application run fine with using the string connection

But because my database has a lot of tabel I need to scaffold them to my database.

My String Connection in appsettings.json is:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:XXXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=presupuesto_apu;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=presupuesto_user;Password=XXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

My command on Package manager Console :

```
Scaffold-DbContext -provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -connection "DefaultConnection"
```

The error that I am getting is:
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

I try with the DefaultConnection and with the complete string

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was doing more research and I found a solution

I have a local copy of the database and I try the following command and it worked, using a exact copy of the database that I have on Azure

```
Scaffold-DbContext -provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -connection "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=presupuesto_apu;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" -outputdir Data
```

If someone can make it work on a remote database please let me know